# Need to remove www from site URL's for a site built in Kohana

Tags: php, web, url-rewriting, kohana

I'm looking for the correct place(area) to put my code snippet to remove WWW from URL

The site is in Kohana and the code written to remove 'www' is:

```
$host_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // it stores the host name / domain name
$tmp_host = substr($host_name, 0, 3);

if($tmp_host == 'www')
{
    $host_name = substr($host_name, 4);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That doesn't belong in PHP at all. .htaccess is the way to go

Comment: Or do it in your router before it hits the website at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

enter your url instead of example.com
additionally this is nothing about Kohana.